# hibernate tool code auto gen template eclipse

Tags: hibernate, templates, jboss

i am using JBOSS hibernate tool for code auto generation which is a plugin in eclipse(my version is LUNA). the hibernate tool version is 4.0.1 final. the issue is that every time i generate a config file or mapping file it is pointing to the old DTD configuration which is sourceforge. the solution i found from internet is that that needs to be changed to "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" instead of "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd". 
is there a way in eclipse template i can change that so it i dont have to manually change every time.

thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

AS per Hibernate Core Migration Guide : 3.6 [Reference](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide36?_sscc=t)

The namespaces for the Hibernate dtd files have changed. From http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd to http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd and from http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd to http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd

This effect/concern is from 3.5 to next versions of hibernate.